# iOS memory leak by dictionary

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios4

I am new to iOS programming and I have developed an application for my client. When I run the application using Instruments, however, there appears to be a memory leak problem caused by a dictionary, but if I release it, then the app crashes. I am not sure what the problem is.

This is image of Instruments: http://www.flickr.com/photos/71234685@N02/6791493522/in/photostream/

```
-(void) generateLiquidProductData:(NSArray*) liquidProduct {

    int _count = 52;

    self.liquidProductData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++){

        float x = i;
        float y;

        if ((liquidProduct != (id)[NSNull null]) && (liquidProduct != nil) && ([liquidProduct count] != 0)) {

            y = [[liquidProduct objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            y = round(y * 10000.0f) / 10000.0f;
        }
        else {

            y = 0.0;
            y = round(y * 10000.0f) / 10000.0f;
        }

        NSDictionary* _gotLiquidProduct = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x],X_VAL,
                                                 [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y],Y_VAL,
                                                 nil];
        NSLog(@"This is y %.5f", y);
        [self.liquidProductData addObject:_gotLiquidProduct];
    }
}
```

Comment: the line     self.liquidProductData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_count];
will cause a leak: you use the setter, so if liquidProductData property is retained, it will cause a leak.
instead you can add autorelease, or use autoreleased method [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory leak is due to this line:

```
self.liquidProductData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_count];
```

Most likely, the property is either marked as `retain` or `copy` (usually the former). The correct way to use it would be:

```
self.liquidProductData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_count];
```

The leak is because `alloc` returns an *owning* reference that you later need to `release`, but you do not release it. You now assign it to the property which retains the instance. The "relative retain count" is now +2. If you assign a new value to this property, the old instance will get released, but this only makes the "relative retain count" drop to +1, thus the instance never gets deallocated. This in turn will also leak your dictionary and its values, since they are still retained by the leaked array.

Comment: but i am using this property first time so without allocating can i give the input?

Comment: `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]` is allocating as well, but it returns a non-owning reference which means you don't need to explicitly release it. Then this object is assigned to your property, and this property now retains it.

Comment: oh!, Thanks for your time, it make me really understand the concept! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use a method were there is init in the beginning of the name, the object who is returned never get autoreleased so it is your responsibility to release it.

Methods which start by the 'type' like "arrayWith" "stringWith" return objects who are autoreleased.

An other thing, you can use Static analysis to find this kind of leaks, it's really easy. 
[Xcode static analysis](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/FeaturedArticle.html)

Comment: Close, but it's not `init` that returns the owning reference but `alloc`. See the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), section *Basic Memory Management Rules*.